# Слайдер на мобильной версии

Tags: jquery, css, slider

[image: Слайдер]
Добрый вечер, хочу сделать такой слайдер на разрешении 320px, по клику или свайпу меняется видео и текст. Как это лучше реализовать? Моя идея сделать `position: absolute` двум оставшимся видео и по клику текущее видео с текстом переносить влево, а следующее видео ставить по центру.

Правильно ли я мыслю? Или есть более разумные варианты? И как сделать смену видео по свайпу(по клику вроде знаю)?

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите уже готовую карусель на jquery(зачем выдумывать колесо) у половины из них есть встроенная поддержка swipe

http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/25-besplatnyh-adaptivnyh-slayderov-tipa-karusel-na-jquery.html

http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/30-adaptivnyh-jquery-plaginov-dlya-sozdaniya-karuseley-i-slayderov.html

http://blogprogram.ru/yniversal-adaptiv-karusel-na-jquery/

http://www.yanajy.com/sdelay-sam/jQuery-carousel.html

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю хороший вариант Swiper - подходит для любого создание слайдера, видео, фото и что угодно) Сам его использовал для слайдера видео с ютуба.

http://idangero.us/swiper/